# How to get all elements dulicate from array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => error_2014-09-26.log
    [3] => error_2014-09-27.log
    [4] => error_2014-09-29.log
    [5] => error_2014-09-30.log
    [6] => error_2014-10-01.log
    [7] => error_2014-10-02.log
    [8] => error_2014-10-03.log
    [9] => error_2014-10-04.log
    [10] => index.php
)
```

Now, I want to get all element ".log" file? example

```
Array
(
    [0] => error_2014-09-26.log
    [1] => error_2014-09-27.log
    [2] => error_2014-09-29.log
    [3] => error_2014-09-30.log
    [4] => error_2014-10-01.log
    [5] => error_2014-10-02.log
    [6] => error_2014-10-03.log
    [7] => error_2014-10-04.log
)
```

Comment: You can use the `array_map()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the explode function available in the PHP using "." as the deliminator

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => error_2014-09-26.log
    [3] => error_2014-09-27.log
    [4] => error_2014-09-29.log
    [5] => error_2014-09-30.log
    [6] => error_2014-10-01.log
    [7] => error_2014-10-02.log
    [8] => error_2014-10-03.log
    [9] => error_2014-10-04.log
    [10] => index.php
)
$allowed = array("log");
foreach($array as $index = $value){
    $value = end(explode(".",$value));   //return array [0]=>error_2014-09-26  [1]=>log
    if(!in_array($value,$allowed)){
        unset($array[$index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` is probably your friend here. This seems to fulfil the description in your question (but not the subject line of the question, which doesn't seem to match the question?)

```
$original = [
    ".",
    "..",
    "error_2014-09-26.log",
    "error_2014-09-27.log",
    "error_2014-09-29.log",
    "error_2014-09-30.log",
    "error_2014-10-01.log",
    "error_2014-10-02.log",
    "error_2014-10-03.log",
    "error_2014-10-04.log",
    "index.php"
];

$filtered = array_filter($original, function($entry){
    return preg_match("/\.log$/", $entry);
});

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($filtered);
echo "</pre>";
```

This returns:

```
array(8) {
  [2]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-09-26.log"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-09-27.log"
  [4]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-09-29.log"
  [5]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-09-30.log"
  [6]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-10-01.log"
  [7]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-10-02.log"
  [8]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-10-03.log"
  [9]=>
  string(20) "error_2014-10-04.log"
}
```

It's easy enough to do with just a `foreach()`, but using `array_filter()` makes your code more self-descriptive, as well as being more elegant.